# Prisma Nodejs, relation with ids to get the name

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

im in trouble to find a way to make this, i want in "serieName" the name of the serie, but always return de id, i dont know what i need to do to make this relation correct, im trying to find a solution, but nothing works.

this is my models:

in Series model, i have a name, and in Figures_table i made a relation with him, and i want to get only the name when i pass the id for the field, so if Series have id: 1, name: "something", i want to show "something" not the id, but only show id.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Series {
  id            Int             @unique @default(autoincrement())
  serie         String
  Figures_table Figures_table[]
}

model Manufacturers {
  id            String          @unique
  manufacturer  String
  Figures_table Figures_table[]
}

model Figures_table {
  id               String   @unique
  name             String   @db.LongText
  category         String   @db.LongText
  price            String   @db.LongText
  specifications   String   @db.LongText
  releaseInfo      String   @db.LongText
  details          String   @db.LongText
  serieName        Int
  manufacturerName String   @db.VarChar(191)
  createdAt        DateTime @default(now())

  manufacturer Manufacturers @relation(fields: [manufacturerName], references: [id])
  series       Series        @relation(fields: [serieName], references: [id])
  Images       Images[]
}

model Images {
  id                Int           @unique @default(autoincrement())
  link              String
  figureID          String
  figureReferenceID Figures_table @relation(fields: [figureID], references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script which would include the name of the Series while fetching a record from the figures_table

```js
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query', 'info', 'warn'],
});

async function main() {
  await prisma.figures_table.create({
    data: {
      category: 'Figures Table Category',
      details: 'Figures Table Details',
      name: 'Figures Table Name',
      id: '1',
      price: '1',
      releaseInfo: 'Figures Table Release Info',
      specifications: 'Figures Table Specifications',
      series: {
        create: {
          serie: 'Series 1',
        },
      },
      manufacturer: {
        create: {
          manufacturer: 'Manufacturer 1',
          id: '1',
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const figures_table = await prisma.figures_table.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: '1',
    },
    include: {
      series: true,
    },
  });

  console.log(figures_table);
}
main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

We used the [include](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#include) section to get the details of Series relation.

Response:

```js
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Figures Table Name',
  category: 'Figures Table Category',
  price: '1',
  specifications: 'Figures Table Specifications',
  releaseInfo: 'Figures Table Release Info',
  details: 'Figures Table Details',
  serieName: 1,
  manufacturerName: '1',
  createdAt: 2022-10-11T12:33:37.768Z,
  series: { id: 1, serie: 'Series 1' }
}
```